# React Native - what does "type" mean on Alert component method?

Tags: react-native, alert

I'm new in React Native, and when I read about [Alert](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html#alert) component, I've seen about `alert` method `static alert(title, message?, buttons?, options?, type?)`

The example given by facebook :

```
Alert.alert(
   //Title
  'Alert Title',
   //Message
  'My Alert Msg', 
   //Button
  [
    {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
    {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
   //Options
  { cancelable: false } 
)
```

and there's no example about what is `type` do, someone can tell me for what those `type`?

and is there a way to showing `Alert` without `Title`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read the source code and found out that `type` is a string defined as:

```
type AlertType = "default" | "plain-text" | "secure-text" | "login-password";
```

However, I tried all of them, I don't see any differences. Therefore, I took a guess: maybe it's for Android only, not iOS, but found out that `Alert` in Android is defined as:

```
export interface AlertAndroidStatic {
    alert: (
        title: string,
        message?: string,
        buttons?: AlertButton[],
        options?: AlertOptions
    ) => void;
}
```

where `type` param is not accepted. Then, I continued to read another similar react native API for iOS only called `AlertIOS`, which has 2 usages, first, same as `Alert` API, you simply

```
AlertIOS.alert(title, message, buttons, type)
```

But the comment says:

> @param type Deprecated, do not use

Second usage of `AlertIOS` is:

```
AlertIOS.prompt(title, message, buttons, type, defaultValue)
```

where you prompt for user input, here, param `type` has effect, if you want user to enter one line in plain text, then `type` should be "plain-text", if one line in secure text, then "secure-text", if it's login credential, then `type` should be "login-password". Note, for Android, you can't prompt for user input using `Alert`, and `AlertIOS` is only available for iOS.

**Conclusion:** I do not know why `type` is the 4th parameter of `Alert` API, for Android, this param is simply ignored, and for iOS, this param doesn't make any difference. My **guess** is, in the early days when react native just came out, they didn't write an API called `AlertIOS`, instead, they only have `Alert`. Since prompting for user input is available for iOS devices but not for Android devices, they put `type` as the 4th param, but ignore it if the app is running on an Android device. And as time goes by, they made an API called `AlertIOS`, specifically for iOS alerts, but haven't deprecated `type` param yet. Anyway, simply ignore the param.

To answer your other question: Is there a way to show Alert without title?

Yes, if you don't want a title OR message, simply pass `null` to the API call.

Comment: thank you so much sir, the answer is too awesome to makes me understand the flow of `Alert`

Answer (score -2):

```
export interface AlertAndroidStatic {
    alert: (
        title: string,
        message?: string,
        buttons?: AlertButton[],
        options?: AlertOptions
    ) => void;
}
```